# Form-submit fails in IE6/7 , works fine in FF3 and Chrome

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer, windows-update

Since last weekend there is a problem logging in on our vendor site with IE only. In FF3 and Chrome it works fine. 
This is a simple ASP.NET (1.1) site using the following code for the login button:

```
<asp:button id="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="dll-button" Text="Login">
</asp:button>
```

In HTML this is converted to

```
<input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Login" 
 onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(); "
 language="javascript" id="btnLogin" class="dll-button" />
```

When I don't enter a username I get a message that it's required so something happens, but the form is not submitted to the server.
Sounds to me like a client (IE-only) problem, but all IE-clients spontaniously started behaving like this. That's why I suspect the server, though. I found out there were 2 .NET framework updates on the server last weekend, that might cause the problems, KB928366 an KB947742. But I can't relate these update-desciptions to the problems we're facing now.

Am I overlooking something?

I'm considering to uninstall these updates. Could that solve anything?

Regards,
Roel

Answer (score 1):

FF and IE handles submit differently E.g. you can't redirect in you submit handler in IE but you can in FF. The above code is only for the click event on the button, which will not be fired (at least not in IE) if you press enter, then only the submit event on the form will be fired "ignoring" the onclick event of the button (The button is after all not clicked).

There is quite a few tho small differences between, IE, FF and C when it comes to click/submit that all might cause the issue you reported.

TRy one at a time and if you haven't already installed try installing a JavaScrip debuger (VS will do or FireBug). That way you'll be able to see the difference in execution between the browsers